# How to get columns when using buckets (width_bucket)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know which row were moved to a bucket.

```
SELECT
   width_bucket(s.score, sl.mins, sl.maxs, 9) as buckets,
   COUNT(*)
FROM scores s
CROSS JOIN scores_limits sl
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

My actual return:

```
 buckets | count 
 ---------+-------
       1 |    182
       2 |     37
       3 |     46
       4 |     15
       5 |     29
       7 |     18
       8 |     22
      10 |     11
         |     20
```

---

What I expect to return:

```
SELECT buckets FROM buckets_table [...] WHERE scores.id = 1;
```

How can I get, for example, the column 'id' of table scores?

Comment: Since you are grouping, there will be probably many `ìd`s on each group. Do you want them all, or just one of them at random for each group?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. The question is not clear as asked.

Comment: @TheImpaler I would like to know in which group a specific 'id' went aggrouped.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, register = which row of that table

Comment: @TheImpaler I added the sample at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can include the id in an array with `array_agg`. If I recreate your case with

```
create table test (id serial, score int);
insert into test(score) values (10),(9),(5),(4),(10),(2),(5),(7),(8),(10);
```

The data is

```
id | score
----+-------
 1 |    10
 2 |     9
 3 |     5
 4 |     4
 5 |    10
 6 |     2
 7 |     5
 8 |     7
 9 |     8
10 |    10
(10 rows)
```

Using the following and aggregating the `id` with `array_agg`

```
SELECT
   width_bucket(score, 0, 10, 11) as buckets,
   COUNT(*) nr_ids,
   array_agg(id) agg_ids
FROM test s
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

You get

```
buckets | nr_ids | agg_ids
---------+--------+----------
      3 |      1 | {6}
      5 |      1 | {4}
      6 |      2 | {3,7}
      8 |      1 | {8}
      9 |      1 | {9}
     10 |      1 | {2}
     12 |      3 | {1,5,10}
```